# promox is blocked from fully booting by ifupdown2 start job

Tags: virtual-machines, lvm, proxmox, disaster-recovery

i have a promox server with ifupdown2 installed.
recently when trying to reboot the entire server promox failed to get to console, it gets stuck on replication runner failing and the ifupdown2 service not starting up.

i have gained access the server hardware with a live ubuntu usb, and i am able to see my vms with lsblk.
as i have found the vms are in a thin lvm

is there a way to remove the ifupdown2 start job, or perhaps completely remove ifupdown2

Comment: Hi, got any backup ?

Comment: no back up sadly

Comment: @yagmoth555 changed the question as the solution to the server not booting was simpler then expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside the ubuntu live usb i am able use lvs to see the various lvm volumes; one of those is the root.
these volumes are lists in /dev/pve/

since ifupdown2 is stopping the server from booting we want remove this from the system, we can do this by mounting /dev/pve/root to some directory, say /home/ubuntu/pveroot. then you can do `chroot pveroot` and run `apt purge ifupdown2` and reboot